# Trajectory of an electron in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, electron, physics

I've been trying to calculate the trajectory of an electron in python without using numpy.

I had to use Lorentz's Force, so I defined a function for cross product.

```
def cross(a, b):#function for cross product
    c = [a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1],
         a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2],
         a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]]

    return c
```

Then to calculate the position and speed in 3D, I wrote code written below.

```
E = [1,1,0]
B = [0,0,10]
r = [[0,0,0]]
v = [[0,0,0]]
force = [0,0,0]#list for instantaneous values of force

t = 0
while(t < 1):
  a = [0,0,0]#list for instantanenous values of a
  V = [0,0,0]
  R = [0,0,0]

  #Bforce = cross(V,B)
  for j in range(3):
    force[j] = q*(cross(V,B)[j] + E[j])
    a[j] = force[j]/m
    V[j] = v[-1][j] + a[j]*dt
    R[j] = r[-1] + V[j]*dt + 0.5*a[j]*dt**2
  v.append(V)
  r.append(R)
  t += dt
```

When I tried to plot the trajectory I had a problem with my z axis. Also my electron does not make circular motion, but goes a quarter of a circle.

Can someone help me?

In my code I first calculate the force, then I calculate position and speed component by component. After one loop I add them to their main lists, v and r as vectors. I was expecting periodic graphs for their speed graphs. However, I ended with an exponential one.

Comment: Why aren't you using numpy?  It makes indexing errors much less likely.

Comment: I only remember very basic things from physics but if you have current speed "V" shouldn't the position be calculated somehow like `R[j] = r[-1][j] + V[j]*dt`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide a [mre]. Your code has no definition of ```B```, ```E```, etc. Anyway, your formula for the position is wrong as Michale Butscher said. See [Semi-implicit Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method).

Comment: Yeah @MichaelButscher you are right. I guess I did not copy my code completely sorry.

Comment: @relent95 Sorry , this was my first question. I forgot to add some important things like E and B...

Comment: @TimRoberts I usually use numpy. However, our professor did not allow us to use numpy for this project.